# JSONArray with GSOn

Tags: arrays, json, grails, gson

I have json in

```html
{
tfegid:
transfer:
count:
names:
       [

 {
 name:
 treatment:
 fdr:
 oval:
 peak genes
 status
 celline
 }

 {
 name:
 treatment:
 fdr:
 oval:
 peak genes
 status
 celline
 }

 {
 name:
 treatment:
 fdr:
 oval:
 peak genes
 status
 celline
 }


]





}
```

format and my class columns are:

```js
    String transf;
    String count;
    String tfegid;
    List<peResultsFnames> fnames;

    String peaknogenes;
    
    
    peREsultsFnames:
     String peakgenes;
    String fdr;
    String pval;
    String status;
    String celline;
    String fname;
```

when I run the

```
List<ReverseQueryOutput> tweets = gson.fromJson(ja.toString(), new TypeToken<List<ReverseQueryOutput>>() {}.getType());
```

I get Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 13 path $[0].tfegid
error.Can anybody help me with error

It is nested json array with multiple tfegids and within that json array multiple filenames

Comment: Does your JSON contain any values actually? And you should also provide the full class. Pleas read [MCVE howto](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the error states that the field `tfegid` was modelled as a `String`, but in the json came as an array. Are you sure this field should be a string?

Comment: yes, one of the values of tfegid was array actually .. I found that out ..when I removed that it worked perfectly. Thank you